# Merge Sort on Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

How do I merge 2 given DLists without having to sort them first?
My Sort function doesn't seem to work (it doesn't merge items) when I display on screen

```
DoublyLinkedList MergeSort(DoublyLinkedList &ls1, DoublyLinkedList &ls2)
{
    DoublyLinkedList ls;
    Initial(ls);
    if(isEmpty(ls1))
        return ls2;
    if(isEmpty(ls2))
        return ls1;
    if(ls1.head->data <= ls2.head->data)
    {
        InsertLast(ls, ls1.head->data);
        RemoveFirst(ls1);
    }
    else
    {
        InsertLast(ls, ls2.head->data);
        RemoveFirst(ls2);
    }
    ls = MergeSort(ls1, ls2);
    return ls;
}
```

Here my main

```
int main()
{
    DoublyLinkedList ls1,ls2,ls;
    Initial(ls1);
    Initial(ls2);
    Initial(ls);
    InsertLast(ls1, 9);
    InsertLast(ls1, 5);
    InsertLast(ls1, 1);
    InsertLast(ls1, 4);
    InsertLast(ls1, 3);
    InsertLast(ls2, 12);
    InsertLast(ls2, 6);
    InsertLast(ls2, 2);
    ls=MergeSort(ls1, ls2);
    Print(ls);
    return 0;
}
```

*Outptut: 9 5 1 4 3 12 6 2*

Comment: You'll need the lists to be sorted before you can merge them.  Fortunately, any zero-item or one-item list is already sorted for you, and a two-item list can be sorted with a single (compare-the-two-items-and-swap-if-necessary).  For any list longer than two items, you can always cut the list into two smaller lists, then call your sort-function recursively on each of the two smaller lists, then merge the two now-sorted lists back together.

Comment: so sorting 2 lists first are necessary right?

Comment: @Arkadian Yes, that’s how merge sort works — by merging shorter **sorted** lists into longer sorted lists. If pre-sorting was *not* needed, it would be a “sub-*n*log*n*” (in fact linear) generic sorting algorithm, which is a bit like a computer science equivalent of a *perpetuum mobile*.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek I can guess why you said "linear", but in fact if pre-sorting was not needed, then the result would be constant time sorting. Take your unsorted list and merge it with an empty list. :)

Comment: @JaMiT I *may* have underestimated the true potential of a *perpetuum mobile*, but maybe not… The linear vs. constant outcome depends on how the magic *merging* with the empty list is done. I would assume that one still needs to do *something* to the entire unsorted list, not just to the empty one, so it would still be linear magic, not constant magic.

Comment: Can you add the definitions of the functions that you call and the structs/classes you use?

Comment: (For lists of non-trivial size, it will be less effort to sort ignoring one of the link directions an establishing that direction in a final phase.)

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek *"The linear vs. constant outcome depends on how the magic merging with the empty list is done."* -- the standard approach is the method shown in the question: simply return the other list, which is a constant-time operation. *OP (Arkadian): This a useful test case for the theory that pre-sorting is not necessary. It should be easy to verify that the merge with an empty list correctly follows the usual pattern. Next, try to merge an unsorted list with an empty list. The result is unsorted, landing a severe blow to the theory. **One should always check edge cases.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting the comments I've fixed the function. Reusing QSort to sort the given lists

```
DoublyLinkedList MergeSort(DoublyLinkedList &ls1, DoublyLinkedList &ls2)
{
    DoublyLinkedList ls;
    Initial(ls);
    if(isEmpty(ls1))
        return ls2;
    else if(isEmpty(ls2))
        return ls1;
    QuickSort(ls1);
    QuickSort(ls2);
    Node *p = ls1.head;
    Node *q = ls2.head;
    while(p != NULL && q != NULL)
    {
        if(p->data <= q->data)
        {
            InsertLast(ls, p->data);
            p = p->next;
        }
        else
        {
            InsertLast(ls, q->data);
            q = q->next;
        }
    }
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        InsertLast(ls, p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    while(q != NULL)
    {
        InsertLast(ls, q->data);
        q = q->next;
    }
    return ls;
}
```

Here my sub function(InsertLast)

```
void InsertLast(DoublyLinkedList &ls, int data)
{
    Node *p = CreateNode(data);
    if(p == NULL)
        return;
    if(isEmpty(ls))
    {
        ls.head = ls.tail = p;
    }
    else
    {
        ls.tail->next = p;
        p->prev = ls.tail;
        ls.tail = p;
    }
}
```